# How to reference ManyToMany table in JPA without extra classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Say I have the following classes:

**Course class:**

```java
@Entity
public class Course {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
    name = "course_subject", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "courseId"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subjectId"))
    Set<Subject> subjects;
}
```

**Subject class**

```java
@Entity
public class Subject {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjects")
    Set<Course> courses;
}
```

This creates the correct schema on the database. However, what if I want to give the generated `course_subject` table an `id` field and then reference this table in another class? Like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Class {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    // How to reference the generated table?
    private Long courseSubjectId;
}
```

Is there any way to do that via JPA without creating extra java classes?

Comment: No, there isn't. If it needs an ID and you need to reference it somewhere, it should be an entity.

Comment: @JBNizet I was already expecting that answer. I just asked this question out of pure laziness, hoping that I wouldn't need to do any huge refactorings on my code. Thanks for the quick response! This is also probably the reason why I couldn't find any questions asking something like that. It's because it can't be done that way.